# DataGridView control not showing changes as expected

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

I'm trying to learn how to bind object data to a datagridview (DGV) control so it shows the value of the object's properties. I'm having trouble to get the DGV change automatically when the object's properties are modified.

However, if I call the DGV.Refresh() method, everything works fine!

Is there a way of making the DGV refresh automatically (without having to manually call the Refresh() method) when the data source is changed?

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private objetos As New System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of ClasePrueba)
Private bs As New BindingSource

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim a As New ClasePrueba(1.1, True, 1)
    Dim b As New ClasePrueba(2.2, False, 2)
    Dim c As New ClasePrueba(3.3, True, 3)
    objetos.Add(a)
    objetos.Add(b)
    objetos.Add(c)

    bs.DataSource = objetos
    dgvDatos.DataSource = bs

End Sub

Private Sub btnCambiarDatos_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCambiarDatos.Click
    For Each objeto As ClasePrueba In bs
        objeto.Prop1 = objeto.Prop1 + 1.5
        objeto.Prop2 = Not objeto.Prop2
        objeto.Prop3 = objeto.Prop3 + 1
    Next
    'dgvDatos.Refresh()
End Sub
EndClass
```

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of automatic refresh do you want? One that takes place every x ms? One that takes place every time you change something in your BindingSource? And why?

Comment: Good question... this DGV is only for showing information to the user of the application, so a refresh each 1 second would be fine. It would be even better to let the user select this refreshing rate. Could you give some advice about how would yo do this?

Comment: Well the easiest way to implement that is a Timer that ticks every x seconds (specifieable by the user). The handeling sub then calles the refresh method... But still, though i don't know much about your application, it seems that most of the time the refresh method is gonna change exactly: nothing... why don't call refresh every time you change something in the data source... you could create your own DataSource class implementing something like AutoRefresh...

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The solution you propose seems elegant, but the fact is that the state of the objects I want to show changes quite often, so maybe the Timer solution is simpler... Anyway, I'm always reluctant to use Timers, but I will try. Thanks again!